# CommonJS support in node.js - why obsolete and/or how does it work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, commonjs

Some time ago I read that entire *node.js* platform relies on `CommonJS` specification of module loading. Precisely, this is an API for all `require` calls:

```
var abc = require('./abc');
```

Unfortunately, I can't recall the source - but that's how I understood it. And now, as I wanted to refresh my knowledge about CommonJS, I found that [node.js dropped CommonJS in 2013](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CommonJS). To quote:

> In May 2013, Isaac Z. Schlueter, the author of npm, the package manager for Node.js, said CommonJS is being made obsolete by Node.js, and is avoided by the core Node.js developers.

My question is - what is the standard that node.js bases its `require` functions? Is there any standard - or did the node.js implementation just fork out from CommonJS? What where the reasons for making it obsolete?

Comment: I believe this rather means that Node doesn't try to be fully compatible with CommonJS, but that doesn't mean it doesn't use its module system.